# how to remove port 8000 from the webpages URL http://dev.myapplication.io:8000. I wanna my url like be http://dev.myapplication.io

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services

i build a website by using django, reactjs,aws. And I want to remove port 8000 from the url. http://dev.myapplication.io:8000

Comment: Configuring web hosting (local or remote) is usually off-topic on SO (unless it is code to configure hosting)... If you just need to show how to construct url with code in some language - tag it appropriately and show what you've tried.

Comment: Hi Alexei, thanks for suggesting. I have done django backend code correctly. now someone suggested me it's problem of AWS configure

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which boilerplate you did use to create your app, if you are using react-create-app then add PORT=80 to ur .env file, but you shouldn't worry about that because the PORT is ignored when u deploy for production check https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration
it will be helpful if you can specify what are you using to create your app.